# swift app share extensions

Tags: ios, swift

Суть задачи : пользователь выбирает фото в галереи (например), выбирает "поделиться", выбирает мое приложение, выбирает папку из списка доступных папок, приложение грузит фото на сервер

Создал расширение, создал кастомный вью (изменил плсит итп) - отображает, все ок, но остановился на получении списка папок (берет с сервера)

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    let userNetwork = UserNetwork()

    userNetwork.getListDirectory(uid: 1) { (isSucess, result) in
        self.list = result
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var dirsCount = 0
    if list?.dir != nil {
        dirsCount = list!.dir!.count
    }

    return dirsCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = list?.dir?[indexPath.row].name
    return cell!
}
```

Но почему-то не отображает список папок, хотя в обычном VC все работает хорошо. Подскажите, мб нельзя обращаться в инет или я не правильно реализовал ?

Comment: Покажите какие данные приходят с сервера, сделать это можно в замыкании getListDirectory, вызывая внутри замыкания print(result)

Comment: @ВикторМишустин проблему решил добавив self.list = result в блок async, почему-то getListDirectory вызывается несколько раз и всегда во второй раз ответ от сервера приходит nil, пришлось еще доабвить проверку на nil. Кстати, такой вопрос : обязательно дожидаться завершения загрузки файла на сервер ? или можно сделать background upload?

Comment: Вопрос по поводу загрузки не много не ясен, вы же тут просто берете данные с сервера. Распишите вопрос более детально.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин мне нужно загрузить файл на сервер (юзер выбрал файл (допустим, фото из галереи), выбрал "поделиться", выбрал мое приложение, выбрал папку, куда загрузить этот файл и приложение грузит файл на сервер). Как я понял, есть 2 вида загрузки : обычный и в фоновом режиме (что бы при сворачивании приложения загрузка продолжалась) - это, что касается обычного приложения, но тут же идет расширение, будет ли работать тут загрузка в фоновом режиме ? (юзер выбрал файл, выбрал приложение, папку, нажал загрузить и я не дожидаюсь окончания загрузки закрываю окно "поделиться")